# Is using useImperativeHandle hook justified here with Draft.JS editor and Formik?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik, draftjs

I'm making a small CMS system in React and I have a form where users can use the Draft.js editor along with some other fields.  For the question in mind, let's focus on the edit form.

The code for the editor looks like this:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Formik } from "formik";
import TextInputField from "@/components/TextInputField";
import client from "@/utils/http";

const MyForm = ({title, content}) => {
   const editorRef = useRef();
  
  function handleSubmit(values) {
     const editorContent = editorRef.current.parse();
     
     client.submit('/api/edit/project', { editorContent, ...values });
  }

  return (
    <Formik onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} initialValues={{ title }}>
     {
       (formik) => (
           <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
              <TextInputField label="title" name="title" />

              <RichEditor ref={editorRef} content={content} />
           </form>
     )}
  </Formik>);
}
```

And I have the editor code:

```js
import React, { useImperativeHandle, useState } from "react";
import {
  Editor,
  EditorState,
  convertFromHTML,
  ContentState,
  convertToRaw,
} from "draft-js";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";

function createFromContent(htmlContent) {
  const blocksFromHtml = convertFromHTML(htmlContent);

  const editorState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHtml.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHtml.entityMap
  );

  return EditorState.createWithContent(editorState);
}

function formatToHTML(editorState) {
  const raw = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());
  const markup = draftToHtml(raw);
  return markup;
}

function RichEditor({ content = null }, ref) {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    content ? createFromContent(content) : EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      parse: () => {
        return formatToHTML(editorState);
      },
    }),
    [editorState]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App-Rich-Editor w-full block border border-gray-300 rounded-md mt-4 shadow-sm">
      <Editor
        placeholder="Enter your content..."
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={setEditorState}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.forwardRef(RichEditor);
```

This **works**, but it brings me to the following questions and hence why asking the community because using `useImperativeHandle` seems like a "hack". Since even the React documentation discourages the use of it.

> As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.

Since I wanted to format the editor's internal state **only once**, when I submit the form, is the code I shown justified even though it "swims against the react tide", by using the imperative handle to share the child state with the parent.

This brings me to the questions:

- Is it okay to `useImperativeHandle` hook in this case, for "optimization" so we grab the state only when we need to?
- Is there some better way to achieve this implementation with "usual" patterns, like "lifting state up", "render props" or something else?
- Am I overlooking the problem here, and should I just bite the bullet and sync the entire editor state with `formik`, by lifting it up from the component, and then format it on submit?

To me, the third option seems to break the separation of concerns, as it would pollute the `Form` context with state logic that just feels like it doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion, the provided solution is a bit overengineering. So let me just provide my thoughts on the questions you asked:

- I don't see the optimization in using `useImperativeHandle` as the value is stored both in ref and in `RichEditor` state
- the `formatToHTML` function seems to be pure function. So why not export it and use exactly before form submition instead of complicating things with `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`
- Here is what I propose and I think it is exactly what you mentioned in the 3rd bullet:

```
import TextInputField from "@/components/TextInputField";
import client from "@/utils/http";
import {
  ContentState,
  convertFromHTML,
  convertToRaw,
  Editor,
  EditorState,
} from "draft-js";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

function createFromContent(htmlContent) {
  const blocksFromHtml = convertFromHTML(htmlContent);

  const editorState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHtml.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHtml.entityMap
  );

  return EditorState.createWithContent(editorState);
}

function formatToHTML(editorState) {
  const raw = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());
  const markup = draftToHtml(raw);
  return markup;
}

const MyForm = ({ title, content }) => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    content ? createFromContent(content) : EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    (values) => {
      const editorContent = formatToHTML(editorState);

      client.submit("/api/edit/project", { editorContent, ...values });
    },
    [editorState]
  );

  return (
    <Formik onSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={{ title }}>
      {(formik) => (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <TextInputField label="title" name="title" />

          <div className="App-Rich-Editor w-full block border border-gray-300 rounded-md mt-4 shadow-sm">
            <Editor
              placeholder="Enter your content..."
              editorState={editorState}
              onChange={setEditorState}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Understandable, just a simple follow-up question, isn't it considered bad encapsulation practise to "leak" the internal state from the editor in the upper context where the rest of the state exists? I perfectly understand that this is called "lifting state up", but it goes against one of the principles of good code design and "encapsulation". Is "lifting state up" an exception to this general rule?

And for the "optimization", yes, you've helped me realize I didn't really "optimize" anything, I even added more unnecessary complexity.

Comment: "lifting state up" by itself is not breaking of encapsulation. The breaking of encapsulation occurs when 1 component contains some code which has assumptions on the 2 component. For example A has `a` and B code contains an assumption that A has `a` in future when `a` changes to `aa` code in B breaks.

Comment: Here when you pass `editorState` you also pass `setEditorState` which is handled in `MyForm` not in the `Editor`. Hence, `Editor` has no assumptions on what is in `editorState` and instead of `setEditorState` you could pass some other callback on the level of `MyForm` which means that how `editorState` is changed is defined in `MyForm`. The change is only triggered in `Editor`.

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the follow-up, and appreciate the answer